# How get rid of -bash: /usr/{package}: No such file or directory

Tags: apt

First, when I never had installed sl:

```
diogosaraiva@Ubuntu:~$ sl
O programa 'sl' não está instalado actualmente. Pode instalá-lo escrevendo:
sudo apt-get install sl
```

traslaction: "`The program 'sl' is not currently installed. You can install it by typing:`"

But when I'm tired of it and I remove it by typing `sudo apt-get remove sl` per example...

I get this when I type `sl`:

```
-bash: /usr/games/sl: Ficheiro ou directoria inexistente
```

translate: "`-bash: /usr/games/sl: No such file or directory`"
instead of:

```
diogosaraiva@Ubuntu:~$ sl
O programa 'sl' não está instalado actualmente. Pode instalá-lo escrevendo:
sudo apt-get install sl
```

This appears with others packages too...

How I get rid of this: `-bash: /usr/games/sl: Ficheiro ou directoria inexistente` ?

I want see the original:

```
diogosaraiva@Ubuntu:~$ sl
O programa 'sl' não está instalado actualmente. Pode instalá-lo escrevendo:
sudo apt-get install sl
```

Output of `type sl`

```
sl está hasheado (/usr/games/sl)
```

Comment: What's the output of `type sl`?

Comment: Try: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/how-do-i-clear-bashs-cache-of-paths-to-executables

Comment: @muru I added the output in my question...

Comment: Thanks @muru , `hash -r` solved it...

Comment: For the future: You can change the output language of all well behaving applications, including most terminal commands, by setting the `LC_MESSAGES` environment variable to `C`; for a single command use `LC_MESSAGES=C [command]` (e. g. `LC_MESSAGES=C type sl`), for all subsequent commands use `export LC_MESSAGES=C`.

Comment: @DavidFoerster What these commands will do? I didn't understood...

Comment: @DiogoSaraiva: Sorry, if I was unclear. I found a question that illustrates it better: [How can I switch the command output language from my native language to English, so I can post my Ask Ubuntu question with English command output (error messages)?](/q/264283)

Comment: @DavidFoerster Ahh Ok, but why `=C` and how I return to Portuguese if `export LC_MESSAGES=C`, and if I use `LC_MESSAGES=C [mycommand]` only apply to the [mycommand], right?

Comment: `C` refers to the default locale of the C programming language (so US English). You can undo the `export` variant with `unset LC_MESSAGES` and you're right about the single command thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash hashes the entries in the `PATH` to avoid unnecessary expensive lookups. Due to this, sometimes outdated entries may remain in the hash. You can clear a specific hash entry using:

```
hash -d sl
```

Or clear the entire hash table:

```
hash -r
```

Reference:

- [How do I clear Bash's cache of paths to executables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/how-do-i-clear-bashs-cache-of-paths-to-executables)

Comment: Thank you! This had me scratching my head for longer than I care to admit! ;-)