# Why do which and whereis provide different locations and how can I prefer one path over the other?

Tags: paths

I recently compiled and installed diffutils-3.3 as I needed the `--no-dereference` switch that is unavailable in the included version of diff. After `configure`, `make`, `make check`, `make clean`, and `install` the new version 3.3 of diff was installed in `/usr/local/bin`.

Running `diff --version` resulted in the same 3.2 as before installation.

commands and their output follow:

```
$ which diff
/usr/local/bin/diff

$ whereis -b diff
diff: /usr/bin/diff /usr/bin/X11/diff /usr/local/bin/diff

$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

Using full paths, I can confirm that diff version 3.3 is in `/usr/local/bin` and version 3.2 is in `/usr/bin`.

Looking at the path, I would expect that since `/usr/local/bin` appears first, that particular `diff` should be executed when I call `diff` without a path. Clearly this is not the case. My question is why and what can I do to obtain the desired result?

Note: Ubuntu 12.04.5

```
$ uname -a
Linux me-AOD270 3.2.0-80-generic #116-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 23 17:11:32 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: About `diff` being from `/usr/bin`, see http://askubuntu.com/a/583912/158442.

Comment: @muru Thanks that explains everything.  I actually ended up doing `export $PATH$` and trying from a previous terminal which worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of this problem was cached (hashed) entries in the bash lookup table. `bash` hashes command paths to avoid expensive lookups.

My thanks to @muru for pointing me in the right direction. What I did to resolve the problem was to use the command `export $PATH$` which worked for me.

Further research indicates that you can find out if the path is cached (hashed) by using the command `type` - `type diff` (in my case) which returns the full path of the command similar to `diff is /usr/bin/diff`

You can take the surgical approach and remove the cache (hash) for a single command with the command `hash -d *command*` or in my case `hash -d diff` which reports success with output of `bash: hash: diff: not found`

you can also take the less elegant and just as successful approach of dumping the entire cache (hash) table with `hash -r` which reports nothing.

Sources:

Experience

[How get rid of -bash: /usr/{package}: No such file or directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/583904/how-get-rid-of-bash-usr-package-no-such-file-or-directory/583912#583912)

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/how-do-i-clear-bashs-cache-of-paths-to-executables